# Using AWS Simple Icons in Visio missing grouping icons

Tags: amazon-web-services, microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

Using AWS Simple Icons in Visio from AWS site. Opened a new template from the vstx file and cannot see where the grouping icons are - for example VPC, Subnet and Availability group seem to be missing. They exist in the current version of Powerpoint template from the same site. I am using Visio 2013.

Any ideas.

Thanks in advance.